# Заливка сектора

Tags: canvas, javascript

Есть скрипт, который вырисовывает сектор окружности. Но когда я хочу залить этот сектор, он заливает только сегмент. В чём ошибка? 
[Клац!](http://jsfiddle.net/8s94grup/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, по какой логике он заполняет контур и выполняет заливку, но правильно будет так:

```
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(50+Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*0)*40, 50+Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*0)*40);
    ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
    ctx.lineTo(50+Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*40)*40, 50+Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*40)*40);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.arc(50, 50, 40, (Math.PI/180)*0, (Math.PI/180)*40, false);

    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
```

[Пример на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e73jjwcx/).

Comment: Спасибо вам.

Answer (score 0):

У предыдущего комментатора получилось по сути чудом. Правильно - начать путь через moveTo, пройти его через lineTo и arc, но без moveTo и потом заливать:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
ctx.lineTo(50+Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*0)*40, 50+Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*0)*40);
ctx.arc(50, 50, 40, (Math.PI/180)*0, (Math.PI/180)*40, false);
ctx.lineTo(50+Math.cos((Math.PI/180)*40)*40, 50+Math.sin((Math.PI/180)*40)*40);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8s94grup/2/